# Can Mongoid `any_of` include use of external document relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoid and trying to put in place a rudimentary search as a placeholder before we look at weighting, etc. The `any_of` method seems to be finding my embedded documents but not those linked by relations. Does anyone know if `any_of` can include relationships to other documents in the db, and if so what the syntax would be?

```
belongs_to :principal #owner
belongs_to :account #owner

scope :search, ->(text) { any_of(
  {:description => /#{text}/i}, 
  {:name => /#{text}/i}, 
  {"entries.title" => /#{text}/i}, 
  {"entries.description" => /#{text}/i}, 
  {:tags => /#{text}/i}, 
  {"account.name" => /#{text}/i},  # Not finding by account name - because account isn't embedded?
  {"principal.name" => /#{text}/i} # Not finding by principal name - because not embedded?
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [any_of](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_of) is the equivalent of a MongoDB [$or](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or) query, so the native MongoDB would be something like:

```
db.collection.find(
{ "text" :
  { "$or" :
    [ { "account.name" => /#{text}/i }, { "principal.name" => /#{text}/i } ]
  }
})
```

Mongo queries only run over a single collection, so to resolve the `account.name` and `principal.name` fields they'd need to be embedded inside the document, e.g.

```
{
    text:
    {
        description: "...",
        name: "...",
        account: { name: "..." },
        principal: { name: "..." }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I'd feared. Is there a standard way to execute Mongoid searches across multiple collections, or does the logic for that have to sit back in the ruby controller?

Comment: Not a Mongoid expert, but you might be able to make use of relations - http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html - failing that would need to run separate queries from the controller

Comment: Thanks for your help. For now I'm collating the results of two queries which is working well enough.